# over 1k recipes!how should i CODE them?

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to wrote an app about cooking and there is so many recipes that all of them have same variables like time,materials blah blah blah...

i wanna know that how is the best idea for writing an app like this ? should create 1000 activities? i don't think so! i think there should be something like 1 java class,1 layout and 1000 of text library in sq lite database or ... !!

please help me  guys...thanks

```
class nothing extend activity{
      text : i didn't try any thing yet!!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 1000 activities !! You just need an activity with listview or gridview (conventional idea) to display the list of recipes and another activity to display the procedure of the recipe as the user click on the recipe name from the list or grid view.

You should have all the details in your SQLite Database if you don't want to access the server but if you think that you will be updating the recipes often then I would strongly recommend using API's to get the recipe details. I would recommend using an API rather than using a local DB.